# flex/as3-when i rotate object on which bitmapdata is drawn thin crooked line comes across uicomponent edge

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I am drawing bitmapdata on ui component by graphics.draw. These are border pieces. But when I rotate or scale that component it creates crooked line on the edge of component.

I tried -> smoothing,pixelsnapping, bitmap-caching, stagequality, and also changed my bitmap to 300dpi but still facing bad luck

- using flex 4.6

[image]

Comment: You're not the only one with this problem, probably the culprit is in Flex's implementation of BitmapData, which returns interpolation with 1 alpha on borders when queried vs half-pixel boundary, instead of interpolation with 0 alpha. Try making the bitmap fully opaque, with those indents colored the same as the background, but it will likely still make bad borders ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have done one tricky solution.

```
Need to draw one eraser on border so that border getting transparent.

/**
Create One UI component
Where you can add your bitmap data
Set its blend mode to BlendMode.LAYER
*/
var imgUI:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
this.addChild(imgUI);
imgUI.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;

/**
Create One UI component
Where you can write erase border code
Set its blend mode to BlendMode.ERASE
*/
eraser = new UIComponent();
imgUI.addChild(eraser);
eraser.blendMode = BlendMode.ERASE;

/**
Draw Btiamdata
*/
imgUI.graphics.clear();
imgUI.graphics.beginBitmapFill(urBitmapData,new Matrics,true,true);
imgUI.graphics.drawRect(0,0,urBitmapData.width,urBitmapData.height);
imgUI.graphics.endFill();

/**
Write eraser code
*/  
eraser.graphics.clear();
eraser.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff, 1);
eraser.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 2, urBitmapData.height);
eraser.graphics.endFill();
```

---

Please tell me if any confustion